# Mocking service with PHPUnit in Zend Framework 2

Tags: php, unit-testing, zend-framework2, phpunit

I am trying to mock a delete Action. The delete method is inside a service, so I would like to mock the service that is requested inside the controller.

This is the delete action:

```
public function deleteAction()
{
    try {
        $internId = $this->params()->fromRoute('id', 0);
        $this->getServiceLocator()->get('internService')->removeIntern($internId);
    } catch (Exception $e) {
        $this->flashMessenger()->addErrorMessage($e->getMessage() . '<br>' . $e->getTraceAsString());
    }
    return $this->redirect()->toRoute('intern/list');
}
```

This is the service action performed:

```
 public function removeIntern($internId)
{
    try {
        $intern = $this->getIntern($internId);
        $this->removeEntity($intern);
        $this->flashMessenger()->addSuccessMessage("Intern has Successfully been Removed");
    } catch (Exception $e) {

    }
}
```

I would like to mock this method inside my test.

I have tried this:

```
 public function testDeleteAction()
{
    $this->mockBjy();
    $this->mockZFC();

   $internMock = $this->getMockBuilder('Intern\Service\internService')
                        ->disableOriginalConstructor()
                        ->getMock();

$internMock->expects($this->any())
                ->method('removeIntern')
                ->will($this->returnValue(null));

$serviceManager = $this->getApplicationServiceLocator();
$serviceManager->setAllowOverride(true);
$serviceManager->setService('Intern\Service\internService', $internMock);

    $this->dispatch('/intern/delete/86');
    $this->assertModuleName('intern');
    $this->assertControllerName('intern\controller\intern');
    $this->assertControllerClass('InternController');
    $this->assertActionName('delete');
    $this->assertMatchedRouteName('intern/delete');
}
```

I get the error in console when running PHPUnit command:

> EntityManager#Remove() expects parameter 1 to be an entity object, NULL given.

Any help would be appreciated, thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It looks like you are not setting the mock in your service manager properly.  You are getting the service with `internService` in your action.  And in your test, you are placing your mock in `Intern\Service\internService`.

So what is happening is that you are using the real service rather than your mock.  Change your setService call to this:

```
$serviceManager->setService('internService', $internMock);
```

Comment: Awesome, did not even think spotting that. Thanks for the help.